# Powershell - Formatting output .txt file

Tags: powershell, format, text-files

I believe this is fairly simple

I have a script that at the end  outputs to a .txt file

```
## Output the product list to text file ##
$SoftwareList | Out-File C:\Temp\$Computer-SoftwareList.txt
```

It presents the results as:

"Adobe Flash Player 15 ActiveX Defender Console ImgBurn Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended Mozilla Firefox 33.1"

I simply want it to present within the text file as a list like this please:

Adobe Flash Player 15 ActiveX 
Defender Console 
ImgBurn 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended 
Mozilla Firefox 33.1

Comment: Is `$SoftwareList` an array or a string? (`$SoftwareList.GetType().FullName`)

Answer (score 0):

It depends to your variable $SoftwareList. If it is in array form the Out-File is created with spaces:

```
$SoftwareList = @("A A", "B B", "C");

## Output the product list to text file ##
$SoftwareList | Out-File C:\Temp\test.txt
```

Gives the following output:

```
A A
B B
C
```

So you have to change the way you create your variable software list.

If you retrieve all in one string variable from an external source you can't do much I think because you can't distinguish the spaces that separate your variables from spaces inside your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I have found a none -powershell way

I associated the File Ext .rtf (with Contorl Panel> Deafault Programs) to open in WordPad

Altered the output filr to .rtf

WordPad opens the file and displays as required